# AddToRole no work because there are hyphen "-" at domain name of email

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller

I have a strange issue, I assigned roles to users using :

```
var userManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(db));
var resultado = userManager.AddToRole(miId, miRole);
```

This code works fine, but when I create a user with an "-" hyphen character in the domain name (tyc.srl.com) and try to assign a role to this user, the code doesn't work and there are no errors. The code runs normally but doesn't upload the record with user and role on the `AspNetUserRoles` table.

Manually removing the "-" hyphen from email make it work fine.

Does somebody know about this error? Thank you...

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably need to allow non alphanumeric characters in the UserManager constructor.  Something like this:

```
UserValidator = new UserValidator<ApplicationUser>(this) { AllowOnlyAlphanumericUserNames = false };
```